# PostgreSQL : query plan delay at start

Tags: postgresql, delay, sql-execution-plan

we are using a mono-column index on a huge table to try to make a quick
'select distinct ' on the column.

This used to work fine, but... it does not anymore. We don't know what
happened.

Here are the facts:

- request:

  ```
  SELECT  dwhinv___rfovsnide::varchar 
  FROM dwhinv 
  WHERE dwhinv___rfovsnide >  '201212_cloture' 
  ORDER BY dwhinv___rfovsnide LIMIT 1
  ```

to 'emulate' distinct, we play this query many times, changing the dwhinv___rfovsnide value each time to get the next value.

The normal query time is under 1ms.

- Plan :

  ```
  Limit  (cost=0.00..1.13 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=5798.915..5798.916  rows=1 loops=1)
    ->  Index Scan using vsn_idx on dwhinv  (cost=0.00..302591122.05    rows=267473826 width=12) (actual time=5798.912..5798.912 rows=1 loops=1)
          Index Cond: ((dwhinv___rfovsnide)::text > '201212_cloture'::text)
  Total runtime: 5799.141 ms
  ```
- default_statistics_target = 200;
- postgresql Version 8.4
- Index used :

  ```
  CREATE INDEX vsn_idx
     ON dwhinv
     USING btree (dwhinv___rfovsnide);
  ```

The plan only start at 5798.912 ! 
Explain only is under 1 ms, so this is not the time of plan choosing.
There are 26 distinct values of the column.
The index has been
freshly recreated.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: the query and the plan don't match. you sure about what you posted?

Comment: corrected, i indeed did a miss copy-paste

Comment: The stats are widely off. Is the plan after a `vacuum analyze`?

Comment: Your query does *not* return the distinct values for that column. It merely returns the *first* value

Comment: Yes this query is a subpart of our procedure to fast distinct. Each Time i ask for the next value until i've found no one left bigger then the precedent

Comment: yes vacuum analyse has been run, the index is just fresh

Comment: What is the size of an index?

Comment: @Denis The discrepancy between expected and actual rows in the Index Scan is because the expected rows reported does not take the limit into account, while the actual rows does.  It doesn't indicate out-of-date stats.  Notice how the Limit node down-rates both the expected rows and the expected cost of its child.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko index is about 10go

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your remarks and the pgperf mailing list we found the problem.

This delay at the beginning of the plan is the time to get the first row from the index, so it really about index reading.

My index was fresh, and my vacuum too. **BUT** we had some queries **IDLE in transation** witch disallow vacuum to do the job.

Explaination :

given a table MY_TABLE with millions of rows, equally reparted by column DATA_VERSION ( 10 millions each) and an index on DATA_VERSION column

-> STEP 1 i play a query that stay in **IDLE in transation**

-> STEP 2 i **remove** all rows from MY_TABLE where DATA_VERSION = 100 and 200

-> STEP 3 i use **vacuum** : vacuum cant remove reference on rows with version 100 & 200 because of STEP 1 still **IDLE in transation**

-> STEP 4 i **do a query** on MY_TABLE **using the index on DATA_VERSION** to get all DATA_VERSION

-> the **index see the version 100**, try to get the first line **to be sure it's visible in table... it's not**, **try again with ALL OTHER ROW ... all are gone**. THE FULL data on the table has been read for nothing.... many seconds of io are lost

SOLUTION : avoid STEP 1 stayng forever to allow vacuum dereference version 100 & 200 from index